# grid floor change possible?

Tags: modeling

The grid floor in blender is XY. Can this be changed to another combination of X, Y and Z, say to XZ, or something else? Note, that this does not impact what coordinate system is used at all.

Comment: No, you can't, sadly...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closest thing is to switch to quad view <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Q</kbd>, then Blender displays a grid in front, top and right view (orthographic).

[image]

Comment: Also back, left, and bottom views. You can use `Numpad 5` to switch to quad view.